# HTML to Query Source - URL ENCODING(Answer)

Tags: php, html, urlencode

What is the following conversion called? Is there any way to generate this source inside PHP from a textbox I input from and what is this process called?

**Original**

```
Title here

Description located here

enter

enter

last text
```

**Source**

> jobdesc=Title+here%0D%0A%0D%0ADescription+located+here%0D%0A%0D%0Aenter%0D%0A%0D%0Aenter%0D%0A%0D%0Alast+text&curlsubmit=submit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is [URL encoded](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php), and you can use:

```
$encoded = urlencode($input);
```

In addition to the URL encoding, your example also has `&curlsubmit=submit` appended which isn't present in the text.

To get the exact same output:

```
$output = 'jobdesc=' . urlencode($input) . '&curlsubmit=submit';
```

URL encoding is a standard format for encoding query strings and form data that is used by all browsers. It prevents special characters such as `&` from breaking the key-value format of the string.

[More info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

Comment: Exactly what i needed. Thank you so much. I love your explanation and examples, Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you have your form method marked as **GET** and you press submit button then it will appear in your url adress. It is called url encoding.

In php you can change text to such format with `urlencode();` function;
To decode string encoded with Url encode use [urldecode()](https://www.php.net/urldecode)

Read more about url encoding.

1. [PHP MANUAL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)
2. [W3S](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)
3. [RFC](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986.html)

More about encoding from **RFC**

2.1.  Percent-Encoding

> A percent-encoding mechanism is used to represent a data octet in a
> component when that octet's corresponding character is outside the
> allowed set or is being used as a delimiter of, or within, the
> component.  A percent-encoded octet is encoded as a character
> triplet, consisting of the percent character "%" followed by the two
> hexadecimal digits representing that octet's numeric value.  For
> example, "%20" is the percent-encoding for the binary octet
> "00100000" (ABNF: %x20), which in US-ASCII corresponds to the space
> character (SP).  Section 2.4 describes when percent-encoding and
> decoding is applied.

```
  pct-encoded = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG
```

> The uppercase hexadecimal digits 'A' through 'F' are equivalent to
> the lowercase digits 'a' through 'f', respectively.  If two URIs
> differ only in the case of hexadecimal digits used in percent-encoded
> octets, they are equivalent.  For consistency, URI producers and
> normalizers should use uppercase hexadecimal digits for all percent-
> encodings.

Comment: Thank you, your explication is definitely helpful in terms of theory. Helped me better understand URL Encoding.